# apps script reocurring out of office message

Tags: google-apps-script

Trying to get an app script to check the day of week when a message comes in and auto reply with a message if a message is received on certain days, say Saturday and Sunday.  Im looking to format the text in the message somewhat to include color for some text, carriage returns, etc.  I have the below code working with two errors.  1. the reply text is not formatted.  2. I end up with a loop of emails if someone else has an out of office message turned on.  Could this be fixed with adding a label to message threads the auto reply replies to?

Thanks for any help in advance.

```
function autoReply() {
  var interval = 5;          //  if the script runs every 5 minutes; change otherwise
  var daysOff = [6,0];   // 1=Mo, 2=Tu, 3=We, 4=Th, 5=Fr, 6=Sa, 0=Su
  var message = "**Auto Reply**  Thank you for your email!   I am out of the office for the weekend spending time with my family. I will be back in the office Monday at 8:00 am.  My usual office hours are Monday- Friday 8:00 am-4:00 pm EST. I monitor email periodically over weekends for emergencies.  I look forward to assisting you.  Thank you!";
  var date = new Date();
  var day = date.getDay();
  if (daysOff.indexOf(day) > -1) {
    var timeFrom = Math.floor(date.valueOf()/1000) - 60 * interval;
    var threads = GmailApp.search('is:inbox after:' + timeFrom);
    for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
      threads[i].reply(message);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your message does not have any formatting. In essence you are sending a plain text response. Use HTML formatting in the string and use it as the htmlBody parameter (read more on them [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendEmail(String,String,String,Object))).

Next up is the loop of replies. Google has a built in out of office reply system and the way they do it is that someone only gets the auto-reply ever couple of days. I would recommend doing something similar. Once your scrip fires, you store the email by using `PropertiesService.getUserProperties()` (read more on them [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service)). So basically you would be doing

```
PropertiesService.getUserProperties().setProperty(email, date)
```

where you should grab `email` from the received email message and you already have the `date`. Keep in mind that you may want to grab all emails involved and inform everyone with the same message, so you will have to loop through them to create a separate entry for each email.

So you want to get the email early on at the beggining of your function and then try `PropertiesService.getUserProperties().getProperty(email)` and if you manage to retrieve a non `null` or `undefined` property, you should quit out of the function with a `return` because you already sent them a reply and you don't need to anymore.